# How to allow users to login with Gmail on my website

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have an login system made in php and a MySQL database now I want it to use by other website also, for example using Gmail we can log in to other websites ....for example Facebook using Facebook api we can also log in to other websites...

Comment: Have you tried [OAuth](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/) ?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil I have seen oauth concept but I don't know how to make our own oauth system so that I can implement my login system to other websites...

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil plz sir help me out

Comment: There is a Walk through on how to set up your OAuth2 Server. Please read [this](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/). If you get any errors or need any help please post here.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil thank your sir ,I will surely look this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table for both of the websites \ login form.
if you have Database with users \ members table you can use it.
connect the form to same DB (with the connection details).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service like [OAuth](https://oauth.net/), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) or [OpenID](https://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled). 0Auth is probably the best solution for you.

This may be helpful for you:
[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578)